# How to write a function that returns the length of the longest word?

Tags: python

How can I write a function `find_longest_word(astring)` that takes a list of words and returns the length of the longest one.

```
mystring = "Red Riding Hood"
def string_length(mystring):
    length = 0 
    for letter in mystring:
        length += 1
    print "Red Riding Hood:", letter
    return string_length
```

Comment: You can call `len(mystring)` instead of defining your own `string_length` function. As for your question, it's somewhat unclear: should `find_longest_word` accept a string ('astring') or a list of strings ('a list of words')?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more-or-less exactly how you have described *what* you want to do:

```
def find_longest_word(a_string):
    return max(len(word) for word in a_string.split())

print(find_longest_word("Red Riding Hood"))  # --> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some built in function ,[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max), but note that you need to [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your string to get a list of words :

```
>>> def string_length(mystring):
...     return max(map(len,mystring.split()))
... 
>>> string_length(mystring)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick one-liner would be:

```
len(sorted(mystring.split(),key=lambda s:len(s))[-1])
```

This splits `mystring` into a list, sorts it by the length of the list's items and returns the length of the last item in that resulting list.

Comment: That works on list of string, but not on string - I hope you don't mind me correcting it

Comment: @TimCastelijns: If you just read the OP's first sentence, it would be ok to feed a list ;-) No, you are right. Furthermore, I've just added the sort key. Without that, length is not accounted for during sorting as I had intended.

Comment: You're right. His example code seems to have confused me there

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def string_length(mystring):
...     return max([len(item) for item in mystring.split()])
... 
>>> string_length(mystring)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Longest word:

```
max(ls, key=len)
```

Longest length:

```
max(len(s) for s in ls)
```

Longest word and length:

```
max(((s, len(s)) for s in ls), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lognestStringLength($string,$getword=false)
{
     $stringArr = explode(" ",$string);
     $getLen =array_map("strlen",$stringArr);
     $max =max($getLen);
     if($getword):
        $key = array_keys($getLen ,max($getLen));
        return $stringArr[$key[0]];
     else:
        return $max;
    endif;
}
```